# Hosting and deploy peerjs server

Tags: node.js, server, webrtc, hosting, peerjs

to help me with webRTC library 'peer.js'. To get it work i need a my-own server, so i try install peerjs on evennode.com. At hosting settings it's stated Startup command -> Detect automatically (recommended) (Your app is started with npm start in case package.json is available.).

So i did the next actions:

1. created my new application-> http://mypeerjs.eu-4.evennode.com/
2. unpacked and put in the hosting source my repository from https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server
3. in that package .json there is: 
   "scripts": { "test": "mocha test", "start": "peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs" }
   also i tried to state (because i ran it from my local server)

   `"start": "bin/peerjs --port ${PORT:=9000}"`

The issue: The application doesnt start.The log writes next:

```
2018-01-27 18:41:41 102ea39d5429 ---> Starting app
2018-01-27 18:41:41 102ea39d5429 Detected package.json start script
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 > peer@0.2.8 start /data/app
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 > peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 sh: 1: peerjs: not found
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! peer@0.2.8 start: `peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs`
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! `sh "-c" "peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs"` failed with 127
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! 
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! Failed at the peer@0.2.8 start script.
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the peer package,
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR!     peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR!     npm owner ls peer
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! command "/data/n/bin/node" "/data/n/bin/npm" "start"
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! cwd /data/app
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! node -v v0.9.1
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.59
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! 
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR!     /data/app/npm-debug.log
2018-01-27 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

**On my local server it's deployed successfully**
I unpacked the archive, moved to `<path_to_peerjs-server>/bin` and used a line to run it with node:
`node peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs`
My server in my home net successfully run, browser peers connects to each other and everything works.
[HERE IS THE LOG FROM LOCAL SERVER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2mB4.png)
But on  the hosting it doesnt so i ask your help.
In log, as i got,there is an error

> 18:41:42 102ea39d5429 npm ERR! peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs

Thanks for advance!

**EDIT** i upploaded the application to my hosted server:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('Hello world!');
});
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

and it works,you may see it.
I feel the problem is with listener port opening

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```js
let peer = new Peer({host:'peerjs-server.herokuapp.com', secure:true, port:443})
```

rather than hosting your own peer server

Answer (score 2):

When you create a peer in the script file for your application, include this

```
const peer = new Peer({
     path: '/peerjs',
     host: '/',
     port: '443'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also remove port if not need. My server config is like below

```
const myPeer = new Peer({host: 'peerjs-server.herokuapp.com', secure: true, path: '/peerapp'})
```